# How to set condition on Repository LookupEdit in Gridview Winform Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, repositorylookupedit

I have Gridview & in 1st Column have Repository LookupEdit. If I select one item on Repository LookupEdit again I don't want to choose same Item. How to set this condition on the Repository LookupEdit ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a conditionally source for Lookupedit.

Here are some samples:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/DQ13616

I think this code is what you need, but you have to use the selected column in place of the second one:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E898

Comment: Hi Tratak, Thats not my task, My task is, let as assume 5 Department in a College, this table is Bind to RepositoryItem LookupEdit in Gridview. If I select CSE Department in first row, In second row/other rows, CSE Department was unable to select. How to complete this Task ?

Comment: Change repository datasource when you change the row, not column. The same ideea !

Comment: DataSource is not possible to attach for row by row. Its common to all rows in a column or common to all rows and columns

Comment: Yes, it is possible ! Using HiddenEditor and ShownEditor GridView events ! Look in the first link example !